# Iterate over a subset of column names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested, dplyr

I am new to R but here I have a dataframe of multiple measurements of a couple of conditions, I would like to perform a nested loop over the columns of the same condition, test if they have two true measurements (not zero) at least, if so calculate the mean of these specific conditions in a new dataset.

```
    > sample <- list(c(8,0,12,5,0,11), c(15,5,0,10,12,13), c(1,1,0,3,0,9), 
      c(11,9,8,0,4,7), c(12,5,5,0,9,0), c(1,7,2,0,8,0))
    > sample <- as.data.frame(sample)
    > colnames(sample) <- c("x.1","x.2","x.3","y.1","y.2","y.3")


   > sample
  x.1 x.2 x.3 y.1 y.2 y.3
1   8  15   1  11  12   1
2   0   5   1   9   5   7
3  12   0   0   8   5   2
4   5  10   3   0   0   0
5   0  12   0   4   9   8
6  11  13   9   7   0   0
```

My output dataset should ideally look like this:

```
> Newsample
   x y
1  8 8
2  2 7
3  0 5
4  6 0
5  0 7
6 11 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define `f_rowmean` function:

```
f_rowmean <- function(y) apply(y,1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x!=0)>=2, mean(x), 0))
```

And then:

```
data.frame(x=f_rowmean(sample[,grep("x", names(sample))]), 
           y=f_rowmean(sample[,grep("y", names(sample))]))

   # x y
# 1  8 8
# 2  2 7
# 3  0 5
# 4  6 0
# 5  0 7
# 6 11 0
```

**EDIT**

As for OP's new problem statement (in comments), suppose your data set is in `df1`, then you could do:

```
res.cols <- c("CAOV-3 Reg", "CAOV-3 Mod", "OVCAR-3Reg", "OVCAR-4Reg", "VOA1056Reg", 
"VOA4698Reg", "VOA4698Mod", "TOV112DReg", "TOV112DMod", "TOV21G Mod", 
"HCC38 Reg", "HCC38 Mod")

res <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(0,nrow(df1),length(res.cols))), res.cols)
res <- sapply(res.cols, function(x) res[,x] <- f_rowmean(df1[,grep(x, names(df1))]))
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clear this up but my dataset is much bigger than this dummy example above. It is actually made of 38 replicate measurement columns measuring 13 conditions, so I would like to make one loop that run throught the whole dataframe to create a new dataframe and not just x and y list

Comment: The column names are :
"CAOV-3 Reg.1" "CAOV-3 Reg.2" "CAOV-3 Reg.3" "CAOV-3 Mod.1" "CAOV-3 Mod.2" "CAOV-3 Mod.3"
 "OVCAR-3Reg.1" "OVCAR-3Reg.2" "OVCAR-3Reg.3" "OVCAR-4Reg.1" "OVCAR-4Reg.2" "OVCAR-4Reg.3"
 "VOA1056Reg.1" "VOA1056Reg.2" "VOA1056Reg.3" "VOA4698Reg.1" "VOA4698Reg.2" "VOA4698Reg.3"
"VOA4698Mod.1" "VOA4698Mod.2" "VOA4698Mod.3" 
 "TOV112DMod.1" "TOV112DMod.2" "TOV112DMod.3" "TOV21G Reg.1" "TOV21G Reg.2" "TOV21G Reg.3"
"TOV21G Mod.1" "TOV21G Mod.2" "TOV21G Mod.3" "HCC38  Reg.1" "HCC38  Reg.2" "HCC38  Mod.1""HCC38  Mod.2" "HCC38  Mod.3"

Comment: And ideally I want to create a dataframe of:

Comment: > y2
 [1] "CAOV-3 Reg" "CAOV-3 Mod" "OVCAR-3Reg" "OVCAR-4Reg" "VOA1056Reg" "VOA4698Reg" "VOA4698Mod"
 [8] "TOV112DReg" "TOV112DMod"  "TOV21G Mod" "HCC38  Reg" "HCC38  Mod"

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We loop through the index of 'x' and 'y' columns in a `list`, get the `rowSums` of logical matrix and use `ifelse` to get the `rowMeans`

```
data.frame(setNames(lapply(list(grep("^x", names(sample)),
                          grep("^y", names(sample))), function(i) {
                         x1 <- sample[i]
               ifelse(rowSums(x1!=0)>1, rowMeans(x1), 0)}), c("x", "y"))) 
#   x y
#1  8 8
#2  2 7
#3  0 5
#4  6 0
#5  0 7
#6 11 0
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clear this up but my dataset is much bigger than this dummy example above. It is actually made of 38 replicate measurement columns measuring 13 conditions, so I would like to make one loop that run throught the whole dataframe to create a new dataframe and not just x and y list

Comment: @Mohere It is easy to change this